# How does 'pip' locate python executable?

Tags: windows-10, python

I tried installing some packages using this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, this fails with this error message:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\dropbox\tools\python\python.exe"  "D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python\Scripts\pip.exe" install -r requirements.txt': The system cannot find the file specified.

Now, pip, and python, are both installed in **D:**\dropbox\etc, the exact same path as above, just on the D: drive.

I've checked environment variables to see if there's anything odd:

```
> set | grep -i python
Path=D:\Dropbox\Tool...;D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python;D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python\Scripts;...
PYTHONHOME=D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python
PYTHON_HOME=D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python
PYTHONPATH=D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python\Lib;D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python\Libs;D:\Dropbox\Tools\Python\DLLs
```

There are no environment variables referencing C:... for python:

```
set | grep -i "C:\\dropbox\\tools\\python"
```

I did not install Python on this machine, it was synchronized onto it using Dropbox, but I have initialization scripts for the console application that I use (Cmder) that set up the path to python and everything according to the dropbox location.

If I try to use python to run pip, it runs successfully:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
(bunch of package checks, nothing installed though)
```

My question is as follows: Where/what/how does pip calculate/find python executable location? Meaning, what should I look for in order to find that C: reference that it incorrectly uses?

Comment: What are the results of `where pip` and `where python`?

Comment: `where pip` --> `D:\Dropbox\Tools\python\Scripts\pip.exe` and `where python` --> `D:\Dropbox\Tools\python\python.exe` and `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

Comment: If I run `python -c print(1+2)`, it runs successfully and outputs 3.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't offer much insight into how `pip` selects a Python version to associate itself with (since, to my understanding, this might include multiple searches) but I think the simplest solution would be to just remove the `WindowsApps` version of Python (or, at the very least, its Windows Path entry). I don't believe that version isn't necessary for WSL/WSL2 and it seems likely it might be confusing `pip`.

Comment: That said, defining and using `pip` globally is generally not recommended for this exact reason. `python -m pip` is a few more characters, but it is designed to work with multiple Python installations and should always correctly install the given packages for whatever installation of Python `python` refers to.